# Require login on each access of Salesforce1 app

Tags: salesforce1-app, security

I would like to require our users to have to enter their Salesforce password each time (or after a certain time of inactivity) they access the Salesforce1 app on their IOS and Android devices. The goal is to limit risk of Salesforce data falling into the wrong hands if a phone gets lost or stolen and the phone itself doesn't have a phone lock.

Is there a way to enable this requirement? I don't see anything in Salesforce1 settings that enable this functionality.